# MediaPlayer not working on Android Things Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I am simply attempting to play a sound using the MediaPlayer. The code below which works well in a regular Android project, plays no sound through the audio jack or the speakers of an HDMI monitor.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.score);
mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }
});
mp.start();
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Does the MediaPlayer class not work this way with Android Things?

**UPDATE 1**

As an alternative approach, I've also tried using AudioTrack to play the sound, this also does not work:

```
    int i = 0;
    byte[] music = null;
    InputStream is = getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.score);

    AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT), AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    try{
        music = new byte[512];
        at.play();

        while((i = is.read(music)) != -1)
            at.write(music, 0, i);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    at.stop();
    at.release();
```

**UPDATE 2**

It was suggested to set the preferred device. This also does not work.

```
mAudioOutputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER);
```

Get device

```
private AudioDeviceInfo findAudioDevice(int deviceFlag, int deviceType) {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    AudioDeviceInfo[] adis = manager.getDevices(deviceFlag);
    for (AudioDeviceInfo adi : adis) {
        if (adi.getType() == deviceType) {
            return adi;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here I set the preferred device.

```
    int i = 0;
    byte[] music = null;
    InputStream is = getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.score);

    AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT), AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    at.setPreferredDevice(mAudioOutputDevice);

    try{
        music = new byte[512];
        at.play();

        while((i = is.read(music)) != -1)
            at.write(music, 0, i);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    at.stop();
    at.release();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to play the sound using the MediaPlayer class and an USB 2.0 external stereo adapter (shown below). Simply connect the adapter into an empty USB slot on the Raspberry Pi and an audio input into the adapter and it works.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.score);
mp.start();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the audio bus you want to send sounds to:

```
private AudioDeviceInfo findAudioDevice(int deviceFlag, int deviceType) {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    AudioDeviceInfo[] adis = manager.getDevices(deviceFlag);
    for (AudioDeviceInfo adi : adis) {
        if (adi.getType() == deviceType) {
            return adi;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then find the audio jack bus:

```
mAudioInputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC);
mAudioOutputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER);
```

Then you can run `audioTrack.setPreferredDevice(mAudioOutputDevice);`

Comment: It's weird that it doesn't work as that should be the canonical way to re-route audio. It works as expected for me.